# Atom.io: Hackable to the core? Overriding Ctrl-n

Tags: webkit

I am looking into the Atom.io editor.  Emacs mode has the following config:

```
'.editor:not(.mini)':
    'ctrl-n': 'atomic-emacs:next-line'
```

However, 'ctrl-n', while executing the emacs command, also opens a new tab, like in Chrome.

Can this be overridden?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'ctrl-n': 'editor:newline'
```